# jquery/Ajax get value of data-id from a text link

Tags: php, ajax

I have A VERY OLD SCRIPT that I need to modify. You will notice from the code it is using mysql_query() which is outdataed however that is not my issue.

I have a text link in a file named surveycommentslist.php. The link opens a jquery model window that I need to capture a user inputed text in and then save it to a mysql along with the value of the links data-id which tells me which unique user ID to connect the comment to. My issue is I am not able to get the value of data-id using the code I have below.

Here is my code

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <!-- common scripts -->
    <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery migrate -->
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap framework plugins -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.reply', function()
    {
       //get acommentuid
       var val = $(this).attr('data-id');

       $.post('surveycommentslist.php', {acommentuid: val}, function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
    </script>

    <?php
         //lets list comments
          $scommentsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey_comments 
                       WHERE surveyid=$surveyid  ORDER BY commentdate asc");
          while($scrows = mysql_fetch_array($scommentsql))
            {
                extract($scrows);
                $the_comment = stripslashes($the_comment);
                $commentdate = date("m/d/Y h:ia", strtotime($commentdate));
                if($touid > 0) { $indent = "margin-left:35px"; }

                //get name of person making the comment
                  $nsql = mysql_query("SELECT fname, lname, userlevel, id AS scommentid FROM users WHERE id=$uid LIMIT 1");
                  $namerow = mysql_fetch_array($nsql);
                  $commenters_fname = stripslashes($namerow['fname']);
                  $commenters_lname = stripslashes($namerow['lname']);

                  if($namerow['userlevel'] > 19) 
                    {
                       $adminicon = "<img src='./img/admin_smicon.png' alt='admin'>";
                    }

                 echo "<div class='ch-message-item clearfix' style='$indent'>
                           <div class='ch-content'>
                               $the_comment
                           </div>
                           <p class='ch-name'>
                               <strong>$adminicon $commenters_fname $commenters_lname</strong>
                               <span class='muted'>$commentdate</span>";

                               if($touid == 0) 
                                 {
                                    echo " <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";
                                 }
                    echo "</p>
                       </div>";
          }
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(val)` ? Does it return an object? If you so you may want to call `val.id` to get the id.

Comment: When I inspect element in google chrome and then click the save button and view the console tab nothing seems to be shown in the tab

Comment: Try putting the `console.log(val)` right after the `var val = $(this).attr('data-id');` The console will display the value (whether it's undefined or not).

Comment: Did you try the markup change as I had suggested. For sure the markup is definitely wrong. See `class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small'` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.reply', function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
       //get acommentuid
       var val = $(this).data('id');

       $.post('surveycommentslist.php', {acommentuid: val}, function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Gian, I change my code to what you posted but still it does not work?

Comment: I confirmed the tag  <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>    The $scommentid  has a value so the issue seems to just be that it is not getting POSTED to the page when I click the html link with a class of reply

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's just an issue with the single and double quote in the `REPLY`. You said `$scommentid` has a value, so I assume there's just an echo problem. Try these:

```
//codes
.
.

//RE-POSITION class values from id value
echo "<a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default btn-small' id='$scommentid' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";  

//or by concatenation if I am wrong with the above solution
echo "<a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id=".'"$scommentid"'." btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";

//or by using the &quot; if I am wrong with the above solutions
echo "<a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id=&quot;$scommentid&quot; btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";  

.
.
//codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Class attribute is not closed properly. Quotes issue.

Change this

```
echo " <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default' id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When I copy-paste your code in a file & execute that in a browser, it shows the "data-id" attribute as blank: http://screencast.com/t/pasXI14dp0x . That is due to the incorrect HTML pointed out in earlier messages.

Even after the corrections, there is still the 'btn-small' text which is not in any attribute.

The incorrect HTML is:

`echo " <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";`

The correct HTML should be:

`echo " <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default btn-small' id='$scommentid' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";`

Another alternative you could try is hardcode some value in the "data-id" attribute & find out if it's being passed. If that works, then the issue is with the HTML & should be fixed with above corrected HTML code.

Comment: @user1739740 Please mark the appropriate answer as correct so the attached bounty can be earned.

Answer (score 0):

**Your HTML markup is wrong**

> You can check that by doing a view source

**Change the following code**

```
echo " <a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default id='$scommentid' btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";
```

**with**

```
echo "<a href='#switch_modal' class='reply btn btn-default btn-small' id='$scommentid' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to return the data from MySQL as JSON using `return json_encode($data)` which `$data` is an array of key-value pairs and when you get the data in your script tag / JavaScript, just build the HTML there and add it to a div instead of returning HTML from the server.

When you build your HTML in your script tag / JavaScript, you add the data from the JSON response and loop over the comments.

Maybe that's just me but I like clean code :)